# Existence of a measurable cover for a content on a ring of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a problem with the outer measure constructed by the Caratheodory-Method for a content $\mu$ which is not necessarily finit/$\sigma$-finit or even $\sigma$-sub-additive.

The Setting:

Let $\mu$ be a content on a $\mathcal{A}$, which is a ring over $\Omega \neq \emptyset$.
Does the following hold:

For every $A \subset \Omega$  exists a $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}), A \subset B$ with the property $\mu^\star(A)=\mu^\star(B)$, where 
$$
\mu^\star(A) := \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu (A_i) | (A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{A}~\text{and}~ A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right\}
$$
is the outer measure constructed by the Caratheodory-Method.

I think it does not hold (you would need a pre-measure and a form of finitness), but do not find a counterexample. I know this is a form of regularity for the outer measure but did not find a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was wrong and it was easier than I thought:

Define $M := \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu (A_i) | (A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{A}~\text{and}~ A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right\}$. So I only have a find a $B$ if $\min{M} \neq \inf{M}$, otherwise I can choose the sequence which reaches the minimum.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you can find a cover $\mathcal{F}_n \subset \mathcal{A}$ with $A \subset \bigcup\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n} F$ and $\sum\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n} \mu(F) \leq \mu^\star(A) + \frac{1}{n}$.

Define $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_n := \bigcup\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n} F$ which is a countable union of ring-elements and therefore $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_n \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Now we optain the desired set $B := \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \tilde{\mathcal{F}}_n  \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ with the properties:

- $A \subset B$ because for very $n \in \mathbb{N}: A \subset \tilde{\mathcal{F}}_n$
- For very $n \in \mathbb{N}: \mu^\star(B) \leq \mu^\star(\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_n)  \leq \mu^\star(\bigcup\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n}) \leq \sum\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n} \mu^\star(F) = \sum\limits_{F \in \mathcal{F}_n} \mu(F) \leq \mu^\star(A) + \frac{1}{n}$ holds so that $\mu^\star(B) \leq \mu^\star(A)$

Finally due to the monotonicity of the outer measure you conclude  $\mu^\star(B) = \mu^\star(A)$.

Formally you have to deal with $\mu^\star(A) = \infty$ but then you choose $B = \Omega \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.